# Flask Jinja notation to return html content not html tags

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

The jinja notation in my html template:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-sm table-hover">
 ...
  {% for a in REC %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ a[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ a[1] }}</td>
    <td><input type="password" value="{{ a[2] }}" id="myInput" class="receipts"></td>
    <td>{{ a[3] }}</td>
    <td>{{ a[4] }}</td>
    ...
...
</table>
```

[image]

The  `<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>` is what has been entered into the database. Instead, of the tags being shown, I actually just want the html output to be shown i.e. [Visit W3Schools.com!](https://www.w3schools.com/)

How do I change the jinja `{{ a[4] }}` to do this?

The app route serving the template:

```
@app.route('/<string:_id>/rec')
def rec(_id):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="...",user="...",passwd="...")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Receipts ORDER BY Date;")
    REC =  mycursor.fetchall()
    mydb.close()
    return render_template('two.html',REC=REC,_id=_id)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `safe`

**Ex:**

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-sm table-hover">
 ...
  {% for a in REC %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ a[0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ a[1] }}</td>
    <td><input type="password" value="{{ a[2] }}" id="myInput" class="receipts"></td>
    <td>{{ a[3] }}</td>
    <td>{{ a[4]|safe }}</td>
    ...
...
</table>
```